# How to automate rewriting code from PHP to symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete, automation

I have quite big project written in raw PHP (about 50k lines of code). I have to rewrite it on symfony 2 - is there any way to automate this task?

Thanks !

Comment: Define : automate? Prolly not, only if u can hire a bunch of monkeys to pull this job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to automate this, you should start refactoring your application step by step.

A good book about refactoring legacy code in PHP is [Modernizing Legacy Applications In PHP](https://leanpub.com/mlaphp)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to automatically convert your php project in symfony 2, the only solution is to rewrite the whole application